# Decryption of Encrypted Vector Tiles Mapbox

Tags: c#, encryption, mapbox, vector-tiles

I'll try to be brief, but I'll share the whole picture.

> Problem Statement

I am using vector tile from [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) from `mapbox` to create `.pbtiles` from my `geojson` data. The issue is, on a web client when I see the `inspect element` and download the `.pbf` and run it by this [(mapbox-vector-tile-cs)](https://github.com/bertt/mapbox-vector-tile-cs) library, I am able to successfully get the data from the tile. Which means that any one with some basic google search can also steal my data from the vector tiles.

> What I was able to achieve

To avoid the security concern, with the short timeline I have, I came up with a quick and dirty way. After `tippecanoe` creates the `.mbtiles` sqlite db, I run a java utility I made to encrypt the data in the `blob` using `AES 256` encryption and stored it in two different ways in two different sqlite db's:

1. Stored as bytes into a different `.mbtiles` sqlite db (which get's stored as Blob). Along with `z, x, y` and `metadata`
2. Encoded the encrypted data as `base64` and then stored the base64encoded encrypted tile data into a string data type column. Along with `z, x, y` and `metadata`.

   and stored the key (base64 encoded) and initialization vector (base64 encoded) into a file.

> The API side **(Question 1)**

Now, when I get the non encrypted `.pbf` from the API, a header of type `gzip` and `application/x-protobuf` is set that helps to convert the unencrypted `blob` data to a `protobuf` and returns a `.pbf` file that gets downloaded.

Now when I try to get the encrypted data from the API with the same header as the non encrypted on, the download of the `.pbf` fails saying `Failed - Network error`. I realized that it's being caused as the header `application/x-protobuf` is trying to package the file into a `.pbf` while the contents of the blob might not be matching what's expected and hence the result.

I removed the header `application/x-protobuf` and since I can't `gzip` now, i removed the header of `gzip` too. Now the data gets displayed on the chrome browser instead of being downloaded, I figure as now it's just a random response.

The question is, How can I make it to send a `.pbf` that has encrypted data in it and this([(mapbox-vector-tile-cs)](https://github.com/bertt/mapbox-vector-tile-cs)) library can parse the data? I know the data will be need to be decrypted first before I pass it for `parsing` assuming that it's decrypted and I have the data that was stored into the `blob` of the `.mbtiles`.

> This Library with a UWP project **(Question 2)**

So now currently as mentioned above (since i don't have a solution to the headers part) I removed the headers and let the API return me a direct response.

The Issue now I am facing is that when I pass in the decryted (I checked the decryption was successful and the decrypted data is an exact match to the what was stored in the `Blob`) Blob data to the

`var layerInfos = VectorTileParser.Parse(stream);`

code line returns me an `IEnumerable<Tile>` that is `not null` but has `0 layers` in it. while the actual tile contains `5 layers` in it.

**My Question is**, how do I get this([(mapbox-vector-tile-cs)](https://github.com/bertt/mapbox-vector-tile-cs)) library to return me the layers.

The code to fetch the tile from the server and decrypt before I send it for `parsing` is as below:

```
 //this code downloads the tile, layerInfos is returned as an empty collection
 private async Task<bool> ProcessTile(TileData t, int xOffset, int yOffset)
 {
      var stream = await GetTileFromWeb(EncryptedTileURL,true);

      if (stream == null)
          return false;

      var layerInfos = VectorTileParser.Parse(stream);

      if (layerInfos.Count == 0)
          return false;

      return true;
 }
```

The tiles are fetched from the server using a `GetTileFromWeb()` method:

```
    private async Task<Stream> GetTileFromWeb(Uri uri, bool GetEnc = false)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        if (!GetEnc)
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        var gzipWebClient = new HttpClient(handler);


        var bytes = gzipWebClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri).Result;

        if (GetEnc)
        {
            var decBytes = await DecryptData(bytes);
            return decBytes;
        }

        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        return stream;
    }
```

PS: Sorry for such a long question, I am not used to such elaborate detail, but seemed I need to share more as Encryption is my forte while map data vector tiles isn't.